# Find phone numbers without wrapping element

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using a regex to find all phone numbers in a block of text. Now I want to ignore all numbers that are already wrapped in an `<a>` tag.

This is what I've got so far:

```
(\+[1-9][0-9]*(\([0-9]*\)|-[0-9]*-))?[0]?[1-9][0-9\- ]*\d
```

It works pretty ok, but I just can't figure out how to ignore wrapped numbers.

Any tips or pointers?

See it in action:
https://regex101.com/r/ACyBON/3

Comment: Process your document with an html library. Travel the tree and ignore <a> nodes.

Comment: This also fails on common USA numbers like `123.456.7890` and `(123)-456-7890`. You should really include upper bounds on groups too, as `11111111111111111111111111111111111111` is a valid number.

Comment: What exactly should and shouldn't be matched? Should it match in the `<a>` attributes? Should the phone number be stand alone or in bedded with other text? (like description). Regex is an extremely precise language. We need EXACTLY what you do/don't want, or we can't provide an adequate answer.

Comment: Which phone number formats are you trying to match? You do realize there are possibly hundreds of phone number formats that exist right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm trying to match most common scandinavian phone numbers, but in this first iteration it doesn't have to be perfect. I'm writing a function to automatically wrap phone numbers in a-tags where the user has forgot to do this. I managed to solve my problem by following the advice of BurnsBA, and I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by following BurnsBA's advice to travel the tree and ignore a-nodes.

```
// First I create a variable with the desired regex
// While this won't catch all number formats, 
// it works decently for my use case.
var telRegex = new RegExp(/(\+[1-9][0-9]*(\([0-9]*\)|-[0-9]*-))?[0]?[1-9][0-9\- ]*\d/, 'g');

// We get all <a> tags with a tel:-href
var $telLinks = $('a[href^="tel:"]');
var linkArray = [];
var content;

// Next we clone all <a href=tel:> tags to an array
$telLinks.each(function(index, link) {

    linkArray.push($(link).clone());

});

// Then we replace these <a> tags with placeholders.
$('a[href^="tel:"]').replaceWith('<a href="#" class="tmp-tel"></>');

// Now all manually placed <a href=tel:> tags won't 
// bother us when we run our regex
content = $('body').html();

// We wrap all identified phone numbers with an <a href=tel:> tag
// and replace the content
content = content.replace(telRegex, '<a href="tel:$&">$&</a>');
$('body').html(content);

// Then we find all of our placeholders and replace then with
// our saved elements
$('body').find('a.tmp-tel').each(function(index, value) {

    value.outerHTML = linkArray[index][0].outerHTML;

});
```

There are most definitively better ways to do this, but this solution solves my problem.

A complete example can be viewed below:

https://jsfiddle.net/krabban/y8r7z17a/